# Customise Newtonsoft.Json deserialisation validation behaviour

Tags: json.net

How can I programmatically configure `Newtonsoft.Json` to treat an attribute that it currently ignores, as if it were an attribute that it handles in a certain way. E.g. if my POCO has a property with `[Required]` attribute, how can I tell `Newtonsoft.Json` to behave the same way as if it was `[JsonRequired]` attribute, when deserialising JSON string to this POCO instance?

Comment: Anybody can help?